# Sharepoint 2013 - Change text value of choice field 'Other'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list, list-form

I have an issue with both JavaScript and CSS in changing 'Specify your own value:' I have previously had this script and CSS work.
The form has been customized with some heading styles within the xsl via SP Designer as well as some attachment fields added into the body of the form. Does anyone have an idea why the script/CSS is being ignored?

```
<style type="text/css"> label [for="ctl00_ctl40_g_bae77b70_6712_4cbb_9705_db9e1a98ecce_ff51_xxxxx_xxxxx"]:before{content:'Specify your own value:'} label[for="ctl00_ctl40_g_bae77b70_6712_4cbb_9705_db9e1a98ecce_ff51_xxxxx_xxxxx"].othertext:before{content:'If Other, please specify'} </style>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("input[value='FillInButton']").each(function()
  {
  var inputID = $(this).attr("id");
  $("label[for='" + inputID + "']").html("If not listed, specify in the box below");
  }
  );
 })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. I needed to add _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeSpecifyOwnValue"); 
I changed the script to the one below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeSpecifyOwnValue");
 function changeSpecifyOwnValue() {
  var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    
  for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) { 
      var node = node_list[i];
    
      if (((node.getAttribute('type') == 'radio') && (node.getAttribute('value') != 'DropDownButton')) || (node.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox')) { 
          if (node.nextSibling.innerHTML=="Specify your own value:") {
           node.nextSibling.innerHTML = "If other, please specify below:";
          }
      }
  }    
 }
</script>
```